# Integrate WinUI with WPF (Existing as well as new)

Tags: c#, wpf, winui-3, winui

Currently we trying to improve our existing WPF application UI. For that, we are trying to use the WinAppSDK to use the Winui3 controls.

Steps followed.

Created a new WPF application
Installed the latest version of WinAppSDK from the Nuget package

Refered the winUI controls by including the XAMLControlResources in the APP.Xaml

But i am unable to access the controls from the Microsoft.UI.XAML. It says doesnt exist.

Please advice whether i am trying with the right way of approach .

```
App.XAML
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" 
    xmlns:controls1="clr-namespace:ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.WinUI"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <controls1:XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"  x:Key="winAppControl"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>


MainWindow.Xaml

<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.WinUI"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        
        <muxc:TreeView>
    <muxc:TreeView.RootNodes>
        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Flavors">
            <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Vanilla"/>
            </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
        </muxc:TreeViewNode>
    </muxc:TreeView.RootNodes>
    </muxc:TreeView>
</Window>
```

I am getting error as  resource not found

[image]

Comment: WPF and WinUI3 are very different technology although they "look" similar, so you can't mix them like this. The solution should be XAML Islands for WinUI3 (as opposed to XML Islands for UWP) https://portal.productboard.com/winappsdk/1-windows-app-sdk/c/9-xaml-islands-use-winui-3-from-wpf-or-winforms That was in the roadmap https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/docs/roadmap.md when the roadmap was updated (!). Now, it's unclear if it's there (I don't think so but I may be wrong) or if it ever will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) mentioned already, WinUI 3 and WPF are completely different technologies. You cannot mix them that easily since they use completely different technologies to render controls (e.g. WPF is .NET only while WinUI 3 is written in C++/WinRT).

The only solution would be to use XAML Islands, however they are not available for WinUI 3 as part of the stable releases. As of right now, the only way to do that would be to use experimental releases of WinUI 3 but even then, it's unclear if it will be brought to the stable release channel any time soon (or at all).